# getAllSections but not these specific sections

Tags: sections, conditional

I'm looping over my sections to produce a section filter group. But I want to exclude at least 2 of the sections.

I'd have thought I could do `craft.sections.getAllSections('not 18')` for example but it seems not.

What's best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I've gone about that in the past.

Loop through all sections, and only if section.type is structure and doesn't have the handle 'pages' (skip that section, essentially);

```
{% for section in craft.sections.getAllSections() if section.type == 'structure' and section.handle != 'pages' %}
  What you want to do here... Print the content or whatnot.
{% endfor %}
```

And if you only want to get channels;

```
{% for section in craft.sections.getAllSections() if section.type == 'channel' %}
  What you want to do with the channels here...
{% endfor %}
```